# Spring JMS connect to Weblogic Foreign JMS Provider

Tags: java, spring, jndi, weblogic-10.x, spring-jms

In Weblogic, I have a JMS Module configured as type "Foreign Server".
In the module I have a Connection Factory set up, and it has a Local JNDI Name and a Remote JNDI Name.

I'm using the following Spring config to try to get a connection, but I keep getting a "name not found" error on the jndiName with various name strings I've tried.

Any suggestions what I could try?

```
    <bean id="mqConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="myConnection"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true"/>
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface"  value="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory" />
   </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to make sure that the `JndiObjectFactory` is bound to the Weblogic JNDI tree. If you are trying to lookup the connection factory from your app deployed in Weblogic, that should work by default.

What value have you put in the *Local JNDI Name* field? That should be the value to be set in the `jndiName` property above.